# ST_Intersection R(sf) Projected vs Geographic data. Significant performance difference

Tags: r, performance, sf

I'm working with OpenStreetMap (OSM) road networks for US States. I read all the roads for a state, then clip the roads to the state boundary layer using the boundary from tigris::states().

The OSM data is stored in a geopackage and its coordinate system is geographic WGS84. I set the state layer to match.

When I do sf::st_intersection(roads, state) it takes about 30 seconds.

However, if I project the roads and state boundary to an equidistant projection (aka EPSG:3786 or ESRI:102010) the same call to st_intersection(roads, state) takes about **30 MINUTES.**

Is it because of the [s2geomerty](https://s2geometry.io/) that the sf package started using at version 1?

R version 4.2.1
sf 1.0-8

Comment: switch it off (`sf_use_s2(FALSE)`) and see?

Comment: Maybe spatial index is used/not used?

Comment: @Spacedman - set _sf_use_s2(false) and got what I expected. I got the warning "although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersection assumes that they are planar" which isn't good. and the performance of the geographic coordinate intersection is now nearly the same as the projected coordinates, aka slow. I guess the question is why is the projected version so much slower?

Comment: How big is your roads object? According to the `{sf}` documentation - https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/geos_binary_ops.html#details-1 - when using GEOS and not using S2 "a spatial index is built on argument `x`". Should the roady object be large and complex (many road networks are) this index building could take some time.

Comment: @JindraLacko excellent point and it makes sense. The road network is about 175Mb and nearly 200k rows. It would make sense building an index on that would take time. From a quick skim of the s2 doc, it would appear its indexing is fairly robust. Thanks!